# Firefox issues with event.target.id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this in my JavaScript

```
var identifier = event.target.id;
```

it works on Chrome but in Firefox it gives me:

```
event is not defined
(?)()gift_c...oval.js (line 16)
add(c=Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=897038643, more...})jquery.min.js (line 3)
add(a=click clientX=1023, clientY=158)jquery.min.js (line 3)
[Break On This Error]   

var identifier = event.target.id;
```

How can I make it cross browser compatible?

Comment: What is `event.target`? Show us some more code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you passed `event` on the `function()`?

Something like

```
$('#id').click(function(event) {
     var identifier = event.target.id;
});
```

Comment: it did solve my issue. Please read above comments! It worked great!